# Deleting rows from a Vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete rows from a vector based on a criteria that if a column value equals the string "NULL" then then the whole row should be deleted. However it does not seem to work. I am trying to delete rows as follows :

```
for (row = MACRECORDARRAY.begin(); row != MACRECORDARRAY.end(); row++) {
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        if (*col == "NULL") {
            MACRECORDARRAY.erase(row);              
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: The iterators become invalid once you modify the container!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the call to

```
MACRECORDARRAY.erase(row);
```

`row` becomes an invalid iterator. After that, executing any expression that uses `row` leads to undefined behavior.

Change the code to:

```
for (row = MACRECORDARRAY.begin(); row != MACRECORDARRAY.end(); /* row++ Don't need this */ ) {

    bool delRow = false;
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        if (*col == "NUL") {
           delRow = true;
           break;
        }
    }    

    if (delRow) {
       row = MACRECORDARRAY.erase(row);
    } else {
       ++row;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's still quite wrong. You are incrementing `row` every column. Not to mention the inefficiency of repeated erases.

Comment: @T.C., yes, let me fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to erase all elements satisfying a predicate from a vector is the erase-remove idiom:

```
MACRECORDARRAY.erase(
    std::remove_if(MACRECORDARRAY.begin(), MACRECORDARRAY.end(), [](const auto& row) {
        for(const auto& col : row){
           if(col == "NULL") { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }), MACRECORDARRAY.end());
```

Comment: Or better still, `return std::any_of( row.begin(), row.end(), []( const auto & s ) { return s == "NULL"; } );`

Comment: @T.C : I am getting compilation errors "symbol begin could not be resolved","symbol end could not resolved". Kindly elaborate.