# C++ Vectors : Deleting rows based on a value in a particular column

Tags: c++

I have a 2d array (4x4) for which i need to delete rows based on a particular value in the last column in that if the it contains the string "NULL" then the whole row should be deleted.

Following from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323983/deleting-rows-from-a-vector) i am able to delete any row which contains the value "NULL". Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector< vector<string> > myVector;
        //m * n is the size of the matrix

    int m = 4, n = 4;

    //Grow rows by m
    myVector.resize(m);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i)
    {
        //Grow Columns by n
        myVector[i].resize(n);
    }

    //Now you have matrix m*n with default values

    //you can use the Matrix, now

    myVector[0][0] = "DC:86:D8:0F:EA:B8";
    myVector[0][1] = "NULL";
    myVector[0][2] = "1";
    myVector[0][3] = "NULL";

    myVector[1][0] = "18:F6:43:E7:ED:2E";
    myVector[1][1] = "1";
    myVector[1][2] = "1";
    myVector[1][3] = "-34";

    myVector[2][0] = "AC:81:12:57:12:50";
    myVector[2][1] = "1";
    myVector[2][2] = "1";
    myVector[2][3] = "NULL";

    myVector[3][0] = "00:C1:41:28:0B:6F";
    myVector[3][1] = "1";
    myVector[3][2] = "NULL";
    myVector[3][3] = "-23.5";


    for (int i =0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<n; j++)
        {


             cout<< myVector[i][j] <<"\t";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    vector<vector<string> >::iterator row;
    vector<string>::iterator col;

for (row = myVector.begin(); row != myVector.end(); ) {

    bool delRow = false;
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        if (*col == "NULL") {
           delRow = true;
           break;
        }
    }    

    if (delRow) {
       row = myVector.erase(row);
    } else {
       ++row;
    }
}
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for (row = myVector.begin(); row != myVector.end(); row++)
    {
        for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++)
        {
            // do stuff ...cout << row;
            cout << *col <<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "The size is " << myVector.size();

       return 0;
}
```

How can i change the above code so that it only iterates on the last column and deletes the row if the column contains "NULL"? I tried using `for (col = row->end();;)` but it does not work. I have also tried to use the erase-remove idiom suggested in the post but its giving me compilaton errors.

```
myVector.erase(
    std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](const auto& row) {
        for(const auto& col : row){
           if(col == "NULL") { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }), myVector.end());
```

Comment: You *know* that the string `"NULL"` has to be in the last column, it's fixed. So why go through the nested loop to find it? A single loop would be enough as the text you search for will *always* be in `myVector[i][3]` (or `(*row)[3]` in your case).

Comment: You could also achieve your goal by using e.g. [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy all rows not containing the `"NULL"` string to a temporary vector, and then just assign (or move) from the temporary vector to `myVector`.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg : I am still a little unclear. You mean i should just have a loop for row and then assign col = (*row)[3] ? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: You only need the outer loop, over the "rows". Then just check `if ((*row)[3] == "NULL")`. No need for anything else.

Comment: Btw.: Consider my solution as a quick fix for your problem... I strongly encourage you to head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for a review there. There is room for improvement in your code and I think you could learn a lot from a review.

Comment: Before you do though, **be sure that your code is already working as intended**. Code that does not work is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @Zak: The code compiles and runs if you put my proposed solution in there. I checked. But yes, as Zak says, make sure to post a working version of your code on codereview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you iterate from front to back through the row.

```
for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        if (*col == "NULL") {
           delRow = true;
           break;
        }
    }
```

Instead of that you should only check the last column right away like so:

```
vector<string>::reverse_iterator last = row->rbegin();
if( *last == "NULL"){
     delRow=true;
}
```

This uses a reverse iterator on the row - i.e. an iterator which starts at the back and if you increment it, it would move to the front. But since you only want to check the last element there is no need to do the `for`-loop over the columns. This is a good solution if you know that it will always be the *last* entry you carry about even if at some point you have more entries in each row or rows with different length.

Another way which might be a bit more generic, is to go along the lines mentioned in the comments with the `if( (*row)[3]=="NULL")`. But I would *not* recommend hard coding the 3 into your code. Rather use another variable (for instance `int colOfInterest = 3`) and then use it `if( (*row)[colOfInterest]=="NULL")`. Like this, if suddenly your column of interest is not the third but the first you can change that at a single place. When somebody reads your code it would be really hard to understand why you have a 3 at a fixed place and having a comment to explain such things is not so nice either - a variable makes it more explicit (probably a better name than what I propose also wouldn't hurt) and can be reused at other parts of the code if at some point you happen to care about some other value in that same column.

As you see there are different ways to handle your problem and it all depends on 'where you are heading to'. That's also why I wrote  as a comment that I suggest you head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. There are a lot of other things which might be worth discussing in your code.

Comment: Why use an iterator at all?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I edited my answer. If you think you can improve it or think there is anything else to mention, feel free to edit or to tell me what else I should put in there (for instance why iterators shouldn't be used).